# Is a particular set of polynomials dense in a set of functions?

Tags: real-analysis

Let us consider the set $\mathcal{F}$ of strictly increasing continuous functions from $[0;1]$ on $[0,1]$ that cancel in $0$ and are equal to $1$ in $1$. So, if $f\in \mathcal{F}$ one has $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.
The function $h_{a}(x)=x+ax(1-x)$ is associated to each number $a\in[-1,1]$.
One can see that for all $a\in[-1,1]$, $h_{a}\in \mathcal{F}$.
We consider now
$$\mathcal{A}_{n}=\left\{\varphi_{a^{n}}=h_{a_{n}}\circ\ldots\circ h_{a_{1}},{\rm with}\;a^{n}=(a_{1},\ldots a_{n})\in[-1,1]^{n}\right\}$$
the set of polynomials obtained by composing the $n$ fonctions $h_{a_{1}},\ldots,h_{a_{n}} $.
Clearly, for all $n$ we have $\mathcal{A}_{n}\subset \mathcal{F}.$
Now here is my question :
Consider $f\in \mathcal{F}$, is it possible to find for large enough $n$ a $\varphi_{a^{n}}\in \mathcal{A}_{n}$ that approaches $f$ uniformly? In other terms, is the set $\bigcup\mathcal{A}_{n}$ dense in $(\mathcal{F},\| \|_{\infty})$ ?

Comment: Presumably your question really is: Is $\bigcup \mathcal A_n$ dense in $\mathcal F$? The sets $\mathcal A_n$ themselves contain polynomials of degree $2^n$ and so cannot be dense.

Comment: You are right,  the question is : is $\bigcup\mathcal{A}_n$ dense in $\mathcal{F}$ ?

Comment: Notice that your functions $h_a$ have negative Schwarzian derivative. The composition of functions with negative Schwarzian also has negative Schwarzian, so that $\bigcup \mathcal A_n$ consists entirely of functions with negative Schwarzian derivative. I suspect this should imply that $\bigcup \mathcal A_n$ is not dense, but don't see how to nail this down yet.